# How do I create a live template with an expression using another variable?

Tags: intellij-idea, live-templates

In Intellij IDEA 15.0.3 (build #IU-143.1821)  I'm trying to create a live template which will let me input a JavaScript function name (in camelCase), and create a constant (IN_UPPER_CASE).

For example, when I'm typing the template abbreviation, and then `sendUserNameAndPassword`, the template should expand to

```
export const SEND_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD = 'SEND_USERNAME_AND_PASSWORD';

export function sendUserNameAndPassword() {

}
```

I have created this template:

```
export const $CONSTANT_NAME$ = '$CONSTANT_NAME$';

export function $FUNCTION_NAME$() {
   $END$
}
```

and within the *Edit variables* dialog, I have the following variables:

```
Name          | Expression                      | Default value | Skip if defined
FUNCTION_NAME |                                 |               |
CONSTANT_NAME | capitalizeAndUnderscore(String) |               |        x
```

Clearly, I would like to have the Expression to be `capitalizeAndUnderscore(FUNCTION_NAME)` and not `capitalizeAndUnderscore(String)`, but when I replace `String` with anything else, the expression is reset to `capitalizeAndUnderscore(String)` as soon as I move to another field in the dialog.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Just press enter instead of clicking outside the input box :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be a confirmed bug in Intellij IDEA: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132965

The current workaround is, in short:
After editing an expression, *do not* move to another field or press Return, instead; click directly on the *OK* button. This will save your edit.
You will then have to reopen the *Edit variables* dialog to do more edits.

Comment: Thanks for the link! It works. I have wanted to do this for so long, but every time I failed and moved on to something else. I'm using it to automatically write my JS ES6 imports...`import yoYoYo from 'yo-yo-yo'`